# Why does getMatrixTrait("transform") throw a DOMException:NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR?

Tags: java-me, svg

It is said that `DOMException - with error code NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR if the requested trait is not supported on this element or null.`

I am trying to flip my SVG image horizontally, but I'm stuck with this error.

```
InputStream svgStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
SVGImage svgImage = (SVGImage) (SVGImage.createImage(svgStream, null));
SVGSVGElement myEl = (SVGSVGElement) svgImage.getDocument().getDocumentElement());
SVGMatrix transformMatrix = myEl.getScreenCTM();
transformMatrix = transformMatrix.mTranslate(100f, 0f);
myEl.setMatrixTrait("transform", transformMatrix);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`<svg>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#SVGElement) elements are not transformable in SVG 1.1 (no transform property).

The "still being written" SVG 2 specification should change that so they will be at some point in the future, once the specification is finished and UAs implement it.

If you want to set a transform, put the content to be transformed in a transformable container e.g. a `<g>` element and transform that.